# How to solve continuous wordpress redirect and injection hacking?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, javascript-injection

I'm experiencing security issues with multiple wordpress sites I host. All the sites have different themes, and are on different servers and isolated within different users. They have been running for a few months without issues. However, last week, a few of them got compromised by :

1. Redirecting traffic to spam
2. Showing weird / corrupted files in the Files system, including extra files AND content added to .php files (encoded headers)
3. An abuse alert from our cloud provider : A large bank contacted them saying our IP address was being used to conduct phishing attacks.
4. Servers are running high in terms of PHP processes (very high load, CPU and RAM usage)

In response to that, I have :

1. Copied from a backup the SQL and Wordpress files from 1 month ago
2. Replaced the entire `/wp-includes/ and /wp-admin/` with the official Wordpress Files
3. Checked for any headers change in source files, extra files, etc.
4. Manually re-installed on a new server, with a new IP.
5. Run a security check with Wordfence and GotMLS. Nothing turned up - All is clean

All was fine all week-end. A few brute-force attack, but nothing out of the ordinary. However, this morning my client let's me know that one of his sites has started re-directing to malicious sites again !

Any ideas how to solve this ?

I'm running :

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64
RunCloud.io
PHP 7.4
NginX + Apache (.htaccess disabled) 
Let's Encrypt (they are all SSL sites)
```

Comment: "Copied from a backup the SQL and Wordpress files from 1 month ago." Make sure that SQL dump is actually clean too. Otherwise you're just reinfecting your site.

Comment: "Replaced the entire /wp-includes/ and /wp-admin/ with the official Wordpress Files." Did you replace the files at the root public directory as well? Also, have you checked the `wp-content` folder?

Comment: @cabrerahector Yes, manually checked SQL tables and WP-content folder of the site. Infected files found there, removed and cleaned real files.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked all the plugins used ?
There is a chance that you used a same corrupted plugin on all your websites.
Try to scan your wordpress plugins to be sure they are all up to date and without known vulnerabilities.

In general, hackers use google dorks to find websites using plugins with known vulnerabilities, and just exploit them.
You can check your plugins with a wordpress vulnerability scanner, or manually by searching your plugins in a wordpress exploits database (https://wpvulndb.com/ for instance).

Comment: Yes, I have already checked for vulnerabilities on plugins. When re-installing, I also swipped clean the plugins to, and they can be a great source of backdoor entry.